# rename file on sftp with curl on php

Tags: php, curl

Its possible to rename a file on sftp server using curl on php?

I use this function to connect but I don't know if its possible to rename a file on the server

```
function get_test_lines($file_name){

    $c = curl_init("sftp://".SFTP_USER.":".SFTP_PASSWORD."@".SFTP_HOST."/data/".$file_name.".txt");
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_SFTP);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    $data = curl_exec($c);
    curl_close($c);

    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using `rename` command. Quotation marks `"` are required if filename contains spaces. Use always full path from the sftp root.

```
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTQUOTE, array('rename "/' . $file_name_from . '" "/' . $file_name_to .'"'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is relevant: rename using curl on FTP (http://www.mukeshkumar.net/articles/curl/how-to-use-curl-command-line-tool-with-ftp-and-sftp);

`curl -p - --insecure  "ftp://82.45.34.23:21/CurlPutTest/" --user "testuser:testpassword" -Q "-RNFR /CurlPutTest/testfile.xml"  -Q "-RNTO /CurlPutTest/testfile.xml.tmp"   --ftp-create-dirs`

Perhaps there are similar options for SFTP, although SFTP and FTP are quite different